# Мультимедийный редактор: Gstreamer / Libav / libVLC

Tags: qt, c++

Добрый день. Какой инструмент будет предпочтительнее для написания простого редактор-мультиплексора на Qt: GStreamer, Libav или libVLC? Из необходимого функционала: кодирование-декодирование видео/аудио, мультиплексинг. Чем проще, тем лучше. libVLC, похоже, не умеет делать многого; Libav слишком сложен, а GStreamer SDK весит многовато. Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из своего опыта рекомендую ffmpeg/libav. Сначала будет небольшое "вхождение в идеологию", а потом можно будет делать все, что нужно. Недостаток - сложно использовать в комплекте с VisualStudio - сорцы сильно завязаны на новые особенности С компилятора, которые студийный (а там С89) не поддерживает. Но Gcc/mingv версия работает хорошо. Народ сделал свои версии портированные под студию.

GStreamer хорош, если разработка идет под линукс+gnome. В остальных случаях нужно будет много тянуть за собой.

libVLC прост. Разработка с ним часто состоит в том, что нужно создать правильные "конфигурационные строки" и запустить. (мое впечетление от него).